# How to make the routing on a REST API?

Tags: php, rest, model-view-controller, crud

I'm trying to handle a route in a MVC CRUD PHP API by adding it to the URI from an index.php :

```
<?php
echo("<form method='POST' action='router.php/users' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input value='" . (isset($_COOKIE['email']) ? htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['email']) : '') . "' type='email' name='email' placeholder='your email'>
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='your password'>
    <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='your first name'>
    <input type='text' name='surname' placeholder='your last name'>
    <input type='submit' value='Inscription'>
</form>");?>
```

to a router.php :

```
<?php
include_once 'controllers/userController.php';
require_once 'config.php';

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);


header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8");
// Autorise les requêtes depuis localhost
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS,PATCH');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization');

 file_put_contents('debug.log', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
 echo 'REQUEST_URI: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . PHP_EOL;
  echo 'QUERY_STRING: ' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . PHP_EOL;

const URI_LENGTH = 4;
session_unset();

$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
 echo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$uri = explode('/', $uri);
 var_dump($uri);
 var_dump($uri[$URI_LENGTH - 1]);

if (empty($uri[URI_LENGTH - 1])) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    echo '{"message": "Welcome to the API"}';
    exit();
}

switch ($uri[URI_LENGTH - 1]) {
    case 'users':
        $controller = new userController(new config());
        $controller->userHandler($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
        break;
    default:
        echo("error of uri");
        break;
}
?>
```

but it doesn't get added to the URI : the log file from the debug statement shows the route as `/api/src/router.php`. I have already added some debug statements, as you can see, and they all say the same thing : somehow the /users route does not get added to the URI. I already created a .htaccess and tried to do a redirection on a dummy URL and it works fine.

I tried to put the code in the default case of the switch and it works fine (apart from a connection issue to the database i will keep for another topic).

Can someone help me fix this issue ? if you have any other tips on this subject I would be glad to hear them as I am pretty new to PHP and APIs.